# How does one service resolve the address of another service using docker compose, link hostname, and ports?

Tags: postgresql, docker, hyperlink, docker-compose

I have read several SO questions revolving the same question, but due to insufficient points, I cannot comment on existing questions. Therefore, I must spawn my own question thread regarding docker-compose and links.

I was under the impression that having the following in a docker-compose file would add 'db' to my container's hostfile

```
web:
  links:
    - db
```

I was thinking that my web code could establish a db connection with something along the lines of

```
db := sql.Open("postgres", "user=foo dbname=baz host=db")
```

where hostname *db* exists in my web container's /etc/hostfile and therefore resolves to some address that reaches the db container.

My web application does not resolve to the address where my db is running, instead it resolves to an address (172.19.0.3) and I cannot figure out where it has come from or how to fix.

```
docker exec $WEB_CONTAINER_ID cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1   localhost
::1 localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
172.19.0.2  6f52f9e78f00
```

I was expecting to see an entry for db. Furthermore:

```
docker exec $WEB_CONTAINER_ID nslookup db
Name:      db
Address 1: 172.19.0.3 apiserver_postgres_1.apiserver_default
```

What am I misunderstanding? How do I enable my web code to resolve my db address?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is no longer your classic docker 1.8 or less "link", especially if you are using version 2 of `docker-compose.yml` file.

As mentioned in [issue 3002](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/3002#issuecomment-187885414):

> version:"2" creates a bridge network by default for your project. If you run `docker network ls` you'll see a new bridged network where your project containers will be created. (which makes totally sense)
>
> Docker itself has removed these variables from links on any network except for the old bridge network.

There is now an [embedded DNS](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/19474#issuecomment-173094817).

Comment: thanks for this info. With that being said, [docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/configure-dns/) reads: "`--link=CONTAINER_NAME:ALIAS`  Using this option as you run a container gives the embedded DNS an extra entry named ALIAS that points to the IP address of the container identified by CONTAINER_NAME. When using --link the embedded DNS will guarantee that localized lookup result only on that container where the --link is used. This lets processes inside the new container connect to container without having to know its name or IP." So my app code can connect by the alias?

Comment: Exactly, DNS. Not etc/hosts anymore.